# Adding Multiple Checkboxes with Quanity Fields with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble adding this set of checkboxes with the respected Hrs. quantity box. The first problem is I have at least a zero "0" in all of the Hrs. quantity boxes which won't work for us. The second problem is I'd like it to only add the checkboxes that are selected. What you cant see from the HTML, is that there is logic that only displays the correct Hrs. quantity
box based on the selection. The HTML is formatted from the system that we use so I have no control over it.

```js
// Equipment Subtotals - Cranes     
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('touchend click keyup change', function (ev) {
        var val1 = parseFloat($("#element_323_1").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val2 = parseFloat($("#element_325").val());
        var val3 = parseFloat($("#element_323_2").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val4 = parseFloat($("#element_525").val());
        var val5 = parseFloat($("#element_323_3").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val6 = parseFloat($("#element_528").val());
        var val7 = parseFloat($("#element_323_4").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val8 = parseFloat($("#element_529").val());
        var val9 = parseFloat($("#element_323_5").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val10 = parseFloat($("#element_530").val());
        var val11 = parseFloat($("#element_323_6").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val12 = parseFloat($("#element_531").val());
        var val13 = parseFloat($("#element_323_7").attr('data-pricedef'));
        var val14 = parseFloat($("#element_532").val());
        var val20 = (val1 * val2 + val3 * val4 + val5 * val6 + val7 * val8 + val9 * val10 + val11 * val12 + val13 * val14).toFixed(2);
        if (isNaN(val20) || val20 < 0) {
            $("#element_545").val("0");
        } else {
            $("#element_545").val(val20);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li_323" data-pricefield="checkbox" data-pricevalue="0"  class="checkboxes column_1">
  <span class="description">Cranes </span>
  <div>
   <fieldset>
    <legend style="display: none">Cranes</legend>
    <span><input id="element_323_1" data-pricedef="146.00" name="element_323_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_1">17-Ton Crane w/2 MC</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_2" data-pricedef="200.00" name="element_323_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_2">17-Ton Crane w/2 MC 11+Hrs.</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_3" data-pricedef="122.00" name="element_323_3" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_3">17-Ton Crane w/Oper.</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_4" data-pricedef="150.00" name="element_323_4" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_4">17-Ton Crane w/Oper. 11+Hrs.</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_5" data-pricedef="150.00" name="element_323_5" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_5">17-Ton Crane w/Oper. Holiday</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_6" data-pricedef="160.00" name="element_323_6" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_6">23-Ton Crane w/Oper.</label>
</span>
<span><input id="element_323_7" data-pricedef="190.00" name="element_323_7" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_323_7">23-Ton Crane w/Oper. 11+Hrs.</label>
</span>

   </fieldset>
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_527"  class="column_3 guidelines_bottom">
  <label class="description" for="element_527">Enter Crane Number(s) <span id="required_527" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_527" name="element_527"    class="element text large" type="text" value=""   />
    
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_527"><small>Enter equipment numbers separated by a comma.</small></p> 
  </li>  <li id="li_325"  class="column_3 guidelines_bottom">
  <label class="description" for="element_325">17-Ton / Hrs. <span id="required_325" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_325" name="element_325" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_1" value=""  /> 
   <span class="label"><var id="range_max_325">11</var> or less.</span>
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_325"><small>* No More Than 11 Hrs.</small></p> 
  </li>  <li id="li_525"  class="column_3">
  <label class="description" for="element_525">17-Ton / OT Hrs. <span id="required_525" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_525" name="element_525" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_2" value=""  /> 
   
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_528"  class="column_3 guidelines_bottom">
  <label class="description" for="element_528">17-Ton / Hrs. <span id="required_528" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_528" name="element_528" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_3" value=""  /> 
   <span class="label"><var id="range_max_528">11</var> or less.</span>
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_528"><small>* No More Than 11 Hrs.</small></p> 
  </li>  <li id="li_529"  class="column_3">
  <label class="description" for="element_529">17-Ton / OT Hrs. <span id="required_529" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_529" name="element_529" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_4" value=""  /> 
   
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_530"  class="column_3">
  <label class="description" for="element_530">17-Ton / Holiday Hrs. <span id="required_530" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_530" name="element_530" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_5" value=""  /> 
   
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_531"  class="column_3 guidelines_bottom">
  <label class="description" for="element_531">23-Ton / Hrs. <span id="required_531" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_531" name="element_531" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_6" value=""  /> 
   <span class="label"><var id="range_max_531">11</var> or less.</span>
  </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_531"><small>* No More Than 11 Hrs.</small></p> 
  </li>  <li id="li_532"  class="column_3">
  <label class="description" for="element_532">23-Ton / OT Hrs. <span id="required_532" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_532" name="element_532" class="element text small"   type="text"  data-quantity_link="element_323_7" value=""  /> 
   
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_545" style="display:" class="column_3">
  <label class="description" for="element_545">Crane Subtotal </label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_545" name="element_545" class="element text small"  readonly="readonly" type="text"   value=""  /> 
   
  </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Aaron

Comment: You need to describe your problem in detail, and how you want it to work. `which won't work for us`, okay, what will?

Comment: I'm sorry @jm-agms, We need to be able to add the selected checkboxes without having to have zero's as placeholders in the other quantity boxes. With the current code I've devised it simply won't work. That what I was referring to in that line.

Comment: What I need it to do is add only the selected checkboxes, times the quantities.

Comment: I don't know about the quantity, but you can select only checked boxes with `:checked` as in `parseFloat($("#element_323_1:checked").attr('data-pricedef') || 0);`. The `|| 0` at the end defaults to zero if not checked or `data-pricedef` is not defined. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your direction. I was able to take some of what you suggested and apply it to my script and achieve my goal! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function doMySums(){
    var sum = 0;
    if ($("#idOfCheckboxForThisInput").is(":checked"))
        sum += (parseFloat($("#idOfElementWithPriceDef").attr('data-pricedef')) || 0) * (parseFloat($("#idOfInputForThisCheckBox").val()) || 0);
    //continue in similar spirit until done
    return sum;
}
```

First, the `$().is(':checked')` will make sure that the addition is only performed when the selector is checked. The `parseFloat() || 0` will ensure that if the parseFloat ever resolves to a NaN, then the expression will resolve to zero, and not mess up your sum. This will allow you to have empty inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your direction. I was able to take some of what you suggested and apply it to my script and achieve my goal! : )